# How to use datagrid?

Tags: datagrid, vb6, barcode

I have inserted 4 columns (barcode, name, quantity and price).
When I scan any particular barcode for the 2nd time I don't want the data duplicated, just the quantity increased.
So far I have just coded

```
Private Sub CTbarcode_KeyPress(KeyAscii As Integer)
    If KeyAscii = 13 Then
        Main.MSAadodc1.Recordset.Find "BARCODE='" & CTbarcode.Text & "'", , adSearchForward, 1
        If Not Main.MSAadodc1.Recordset.EOF Then
            CAadodc1.Recordset.Find "BARCODE='" & CTbarcode.Text & "'", , adSearchForward, 1
            If CAadodc1.Recordset.EOF Then
                CTproduct.Text = Main.MSAadodc1.Recordset!PRODUCT
                CTprice.Text = Main.MSAadodc1.Recordset!PRICE
                CTquantity.Text = "1"
                CAadodc1.Recordset.AddNew
                CAadodc1.Recordset!tbarcode = CTbarcode.Text
                CAadodc1.Recordset!tproduct = CTproduct.Text
                CAadodc1.Recordset!tquantity = CTquantity.Text
                CAadodc1.Recordset!tprice = CTprice.Text
                CAadodc1.Recordset!tdiscount = CTquantity.Text
                CAadodc1.Recordset!ttotalprice = Val(CTprice.Text * CTquantity.Text) - CTquantity.Text
                CTbarcode.SetFocus
            Else
                CAadodc1.Recordset!tquantity = Val(CAadodc1.Recordset!tquantity + 1)
                CTbarcode.SetFocus
                CAadodc1.Refresh
            End If
        Else
            MsgBox "Data Not Found!", vbOKOnly + vbCritical, "Unknown!"
            CTbarcode.Text = ""
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Think of it the other way round. - If the barcode **is** found then increment your !tquantity for the found record by one, else add a new record.

Comment: There is an error idk why.... It says "not found the collection"

Comment: Which line is hilighted when the error occurs?

Comment: Double-check the spelling of your field names in your code!

Comment: `CAadodc1.Recordset!tdiscount = CTquantity.Text` looks suspicious.

Comment: Ahh i haven't coded for the discount yet, i just now i only set it to 0. BTW thank you for editing mine. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Private Sub CTbarcode_KeyPress(KeyAscii As Integer)
    If KeyAscii = 13 Then
        Main.MSAadodc1.Recordset.Find "BARCODE='" & CTbarcode.Text & "'", , adSearchForward, 1
        If Not Main.MSAadodc1.Recordset.EOF Then
            CAadodc1.Recordset.Find "tbarcode='" & CTbarcode.Text & "'", , adSearchForward, 1
            If CAadodc1.Recordset.EOF Then
                CTproduct.Text = Main.MSAadodc1.Recordset!PRODUCT
                CTprice.Text = Main.MSAadodc1.Recordset!PRICE
                CTquantity.Text = "1"
                CAadodc1.Recordset.AddNew
                CAadodc1.Recordset!tbarcode = CTbarcode.Text
                CAadodc1.Recordset!tproduct = CTproduct.Text
                CAadodc1.Recordset!tquantity = CTquantity.Text
                CAadodc1.Recordset!tprice = CTprice.Text
                CAadodc1.Recordset!tdiscount = 0
                CAadodc1.Recordset!ttotalprice = Val(CTprice.Text * CTquantity.Text) - CTquantity.Text
                CTbarcode.SetFocus
                CTbarcode.Text = ""
                CTprice.Text = ""
                CTproduct.Text = ""
                CTquantity.Text = ""
            Else
                CAadodc1.Recordset!tquantity = CAadodc1.Recordset!tquantity + 1
                CAadodc1.Recordset!tdiscount = 0
                CAadodc1.Recordset!ttotalprice = Val(CAadodc1.Recordset!tprice * CAadodc1.Recordset!tquantity - CAadodc1.Recordset!tdiscount)
                CAadodc1.Recordset.Update
                CTbarcode.SetFocus
                CTbarcode.Text = ""
                CTprice.Text = ""
                CTproduct.Text = ""
                CTquantity.Text = ""
            End If
        Else
            MsgBox "Data Not Found!", vbOKOnly + vbCritical, "Unknown!"
            CTbarcode.Text = ""
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I can't check that because VB is on another machine here and it's after midnight, but I'm not sure that is going to work. Have you actually tested it and checked the results are correct?